# react Creating dynamic components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have `li key={Info.id}`>
I want to make `<div>{NumberStatus} </div>` output the data corresponding to the `id` value when the corresponding id value is clicked.

In summary, when 'one li tag text' is clicked, the div will output '{NumberStatus}' value corresponding to 'one text', and `{functionInfolabels}` corresponding value.

How would you like to write code?

```
 let functionInfolabels = ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.[0].materialsInfo?.[0].ingredientsInfo?.map(array => array.ingredientDisplayText);

let NumberStatus = ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.[0].materialsInfo?.[0].ingredientsInfo?.map(array => array.chartStatus) 
   

return (
          {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.length ? 
            ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo.map(Info => (
            <li key={Info.id}>{Info.seedShapeDisplayText}</li>
            )) : <li>There is not</li>}

// seedShapeDisplayText; // one two three four five ... 

// <li key===1 onClick <div> Hi Number Minsu, Bar : 1 </div>
// <li key===2 onClick <div> Hi Number Jenny, Bar : 3 </div>
....
<div>
Hi Number {NumberStatus} // one : Minsu, two : Jenny, three : Youngmin, four : Jiho ...

<Bar 
labels={functionInfolabels} // one : 1, two: 3, three: 124 .... 
/>
</div>


)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data (funcationsInfo?) It still isn't clear exactly what you want to show up in your div. It seems as if  you have an array of objects.

Comment: @Alan // JSON data is formed in this format. 
 chart:   
   functionalInfo: Array(5)   
      0: 
         materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
            0:  
             chartStatus: "minsu" 
             ingredientDisplayText:1
         
     1: 
          materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
        
            1:
             chartStatus: "Jeeny"
             ingredientDisplayText:3
             ...

Answer (score 0):

If you could explain a bit more on your question, I think it will be easy to understand and answer.

Here is the solution as I got your question,

in here I'm using the state as `numberStatus` and when your click on any of the `li` i'm setting the `numberStatus` state with the numberStatus data of the selected li.

also in the bottom rendering part I'm checking that the state of `numberStatus` is having a value and if only I make it display.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [numberStatus, setNumberStatus] = React.useState("");

  const dataList = [
    { title: "Title 01", numberStatus: "one" },
    { title: "Title 02", numberStatus: "two" },
    { title: "Title 03", numberStatus: "three" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {dataList.map((val, key) => {
          return (
            <li key={key} onClick={() => setNumberStatus(val.numberStatus)}>
              {" "}
              {val.title}{" "}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

      {numberStatus && <div>Hi Number {numberStatus}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've modified the code to be more descriptive.

Comment: // JSON data is formed in this format. 
 chart:   
   functionalInfo: Array(5)   
      0: 
         materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
            0:  
             chartStatus: "minsu" 
             ingredientDisplayText:1
         
     1: 
          materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
        
            1:
             chartStatus: "Jeeny"
             ingredientDisplayText:3
             ...

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way is to set state value when your `<li>` element is clicked, and then render that state value.

Using a functional component, you can use the `useState` hook in a straight forward manner.

Please note: I took some liberty with your code sample, and added a button tag, and a helper function to set the value.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [infoText, setInfoText] = React.useState('');

  const onButtonClick = (text) => {
    setInfoText(text);
  }

  return (
          {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.length ? 
            ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo.map(Info => (
            <li key={Info.id}><button onClick={e=>onButtonClick(Info.seedShapeDisplayText)}>{Info.seedShapeDisplayText}</button></li>
            )) : <li>There is not</li>}

          // seedShapeDisplayText; // one two three four five ... 

          <div>
          Hi Number {infoText} // one : Minsu, two : Jenny, three : Youngmin, four : Jiho ...
          </div>


      )
}
```

Comment: I think I need to dynamically change the <div></div> instead of `{} text`.

Comment: {infoText <div>Hi Number {infoText} </div> }   Can I proceed this way?

Comment: I've modified the code to be more descriptive.

Comment: // JSON data is formed in this format. 
 chart:   
   functionalInfo: Array(5)   
      0: 
         materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
            0:  
             chartStatus: "minsu" 
             ingredientDisplayText:1
         
     1: 
          materialsInfo: Array(1)  
         0:  
            igredientsInfo: Array(1)  
        
            1:
             chartStatus: "Jeeny"
             ingredientDisplayText:3
             ...